# How to get the values of a column in dataset having "//" in the column name ,using LinQ?

Tags: linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have a dataset `oDsData`.In this i have a column named `SL_NO\\W`.

i used the following code

```
var f = oDsData.AsEnumerable();
var x = from c in f
     select c.Field<int>("[SL_NO\\W]").ToString()
     .Substring(c.Field<int>("[SL_NO\\W]")-1, 1);
if (x.Count() > 0)
     {some code}
```

While trying to get `x.Count()`,i get the exception `Column '[SL_NO\W]'` does not belong to table `Table1`.

can anyone help me as it very important.

Regards,
Neethu

Comment: did you try without [] in your column name like c.Field("SL_NO\W").ToString() ?

Comment: Yes i did try using like that.Still the error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Since `\` is a special char you have to double it or use the `@` (literal string):

```
 select c.Field<int>(@"[SL_NO\\W]").ToString() <-- @ before the string
```

Or

```
 select c.Field<int>("[SL_NO\\\\W]").ToString() <-- 4 means 2
```